# Ruby on Rails escape umlauts in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, escaping, diacritics

I try to post some parameters containing umlauts to a url (PHP Script). So I've to escape the parameters. But Ruby returns me an unexpected string.

PHP:

```
urlencode("äöü");
```

output: %E4%F6%FC

and RoR:

```
URI.escape("äöü")
```

output: %C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC

or:

```
CGI.escape("äöü")
```

output: %C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC

I'm working on Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby 1.9.2 and my application is setup for UTF-8. Where is my fault or what should I do?

Thanx andi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of String encodings. As you noted, Ruby is configured for UTF-8, whereas your installation of PHP looks like it's trying to encode using ISO 8859-1.

To solve this, you need to make sure both of your scripts are operating using the same encoding, or explicitly convert your URL paramaters from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1.

Comment: thanks a lot dan! expected something like this. now I'm using: `CGI.escape(Iconv.conv('ISO-8859-1', 'utf-8', "äöü"))`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use something like this:

```
CGI.escape("äöü")
```

If you got an error try to **require 'cgi'** before.

Comment: same result as with URI.escape

Comment: Very strange it should work. Even there you got the same http://railsforphp.com/reference/url/urlencode . Sorry for not helping you

Comment: if I use the string given in your link, both (PHP and RoR) are the same... strange